# ListItem Template - content not showing

Tags: wpf, listboxitem, contentpresenter

I'm trying to create a new style for a `ListItem` to get rid of the default blue rectangles showing when hovering the items and selecting them. 
here's what I've got so far:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Problem is - content is not showing at all. I tried to do it with a different controller (a button, for example). `ContentPresenter` doesn't seem to work with `ListBoxItem` though...

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add TargetType="ListBoxItem" to ControlTemplate

```
 <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```